# threading calling socket library twice python

Tags: python

My server code is this:

```
import SocketServer
import json

class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True


class MyTCPServerHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        try:
            data = json.loads(self.request.recv(1024).strip())
            # process the data, i.e. print it:
            print data
            # send some 'ok' back
            self.request.sendall(json.dumps({'return': 'ok'}))
        except Exception, e:
            print "Exception wile receiving message: ", e

def socket_server(host,port):
    print host,port
    server = MyTCPServer((host, port), MyTCPServerHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

And I am trying to call this from a script like this

```
import threading
server_thread = threading.Thread(target=socket_server, args=('127.0.0.1', 13373))
server_thread.start()
#after this i have other code..
```

So while it starts the server....and everything is fine but somehow.. it tries to start the same code again..

because i see this error:

```
    Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):


127.0.0.1 13373   <---- THIS IS THE PORT WHICH IS CONNECTED
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 530, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 483, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Users/mohitdeepsingh/Desktop/project/flaskapp/app/sock_lib/sock_server.py", line 21, in socket_server
    server = MyTCPServer((host, port), MyTCPServerHandler)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 408, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 222, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

So basically what i am trying to do is call socket_server(host,port) in background and just continue with my code.

Comment: And you are sure you do not create the thread twice (or more)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: naah.. but rest of the code is a web server.. which starts another server on localhost at different port..do you think that might be an issue??

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Hi.. Actually in the server code.. i wrote  a unit test which was starting a new thread.. so instead of two threads there is just one thread.. but i still get an error :( though the port is open..and the code execution is just fine.. but it throws that error.. any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing(tidying up) after the server closes(or goes down)? Scan and close the open ports on your machine before running the server i.e **ports you intend to use for your server**.

If you do not close a port then the port will be unusable until a shutdown or explicit closing of the ports!